# Thinking Sphinx searching search across all models : number of result per model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, grouping, thinking-sphinx

I did a global search (across all models). Now, I want to know how many results each model can have.

For example, if my search returns 10 rows/results and I have 3 models, is it possible to know that model A has 3, model B has 2 and model C has 5 results? I want to use that to create graphs.

**update**

***home controller***

```
 facets =ThinkingSphinx.facets "#{params[:name]}  #{params[:alignment]} #{params[:tvShow_id]}", 
   :star => true, 
   :with     => filters, 
   :conditions =>  { :ending_time =>  params[:ending_time], :starting_time =>  params[:starting_time]},
   :page     => params[:page],
   :per_page => 20 

 puts facets[:sphinx_internal_class]
```

***error***

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "tvShow_id"=>"", "broadcast_date_from"=>"", "starting_time"=>"", "broadcast_date_to"=>"", "ending_time"=>"", "gender"=>"", "organization_id"=>"", "position_id"=>"", "alignment"=>"neutral", "commit"=>"Generate"}
 Profession Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "professions".* FROM "professions" ORDER BY name
 Organization Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "organizations".* FROM "organizations" ORDER BY name
 Position Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "positions".* FROM "positions" ORDER BY name
 TvShow Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "tv_shows".* FROM "tv_shows" ORDER BY name
 Sphinx Query (1.9ms)  SELECT * FROM `episode_core`, `episode_delta`, `organization_core`, `organization_delta`, `person_core`, `person_delta`, `position_core`, `position_delta`, `profession_core`, `profession_delta`, `segment_core`, `segment_delta`, `tv_show_core`, `tv_show_delta` WHERE MATCH('*neutral*') AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 ORDER BY `model_order` ASC LIMIT 0, 20
 Sphinx  Found 5 results
 Position Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "positions".* FROM "positions" WHERE "positions"."id" IN (54, 142)
 Organization Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "organizations".* FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."id" IN (104)
 Person Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" IN (348, 1658)
 Sphinx  Retrying query "SELECT *, *, @groupby, @count FROM `episode_core`, `episode_delta`, `organization_core`, `organization_delta`, `person_core`, `person_delta`, `position_core`, `position_delta`, `profession_core`, `profession_delta`, `segment_core`, `segment_delta`, `tv_show_core`, `tv_show_delta` WHERE MATCH('*neutral*') AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 GROUP BY `sphinx_internal_class` LIMIT 0, 20 OPTION max_matches=20; SHOW META" after error: Using the old-fashion @variables (@count, @weight, etc.) is deprecated
 Sphinx  Retrying query "SELECT *, *, @groupby, @count FROM `episode_core`, `episode_delta`, `organization_core`, `organization_delta`, `person_core`, `person_delta`, `position_core`, `position_delta`, `profession_core`, `profession_delta`, `segment_core`, `segment_delta`, `tv_show_core`, `tv_show_delta` WHERE MATCH('*neutral*') AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 GROUP BY `sphinx_internal_class` LIMIT 0, 20 OPTION max_matches=20; SHOW META" after error: Using the old-fashion @variables (@count, @weight, etc.) is deprecated
 Sphinx Query (6.4ms)  SELECT *, *, @groupby, @count FROM `episode_core`, `episode_delta`, `organization_core`, `organization_delta`, `person_core`, `person_delta`, `position_core`, `position_delta`, `profession_core`, `profession_delta`, `segment_core`, `segment_delta`, `tv_show_core`, `tv_show_delta` WHERE MATCH('*neutral*') AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 GROUP BY `sphinx_internal_class` LIMIT 0, 20 OPTION max_matches=20
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 42ms

 ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError (Using the old-fashion @variables (@count, @weight, etc.) is deprecated):
 app/controllers/home_controller.rb:92:in `index'
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could always compute that from your search results:

```
search = ThinkingSphinx.search params[:query]
groups = search.group_by(&:class)
groups.each { |klass, results| puts klass.name, results.length }
```

But if the number of results you have is bigger than your page size, then this isn't going to work. The better approach is to use a facets call:

```
facets = ThinkingSphinx.facets params[:query] # takes same arguments as search
facets[:sphinx_internal_class]
```

Comment: thanks, the 1st solution works fine but the second solution is what i need since the result will return thousands of rows. But when i try it i get an error `Using the old-fashion @variables (@count, @weight, etc.) is deprecated`.(this is my first time using TS i may be missing somethg).I updated my question with error

Comment: You must be using Sphinx 2.1.2 or newer with TS v3.0.6 or older. You can either upgrade TS to v3.1.0, or otherwise make sure you're using TS v3.0.6 and make the changes noted in the release notes: https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/releases/tag/v3.0.6 (and https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/releases/tag/v3.1.0 if you opt for TS v3.1.0).

Comment: thanks I upgraded TS to v3.1.0 the error is gone now. I have another question : how can i access the columns of each model in results? in the first option i access/print them with a loop `for res in results   res.column_name`. how do you do it for the facets option (2nd option)?

Comment: If you still want the actual search results, you'll need to perform the search call as well - facets just provides the summary statistics.